# How do I extract the year from the following string?

Tags: r, string, extract

There is no set formula to this column in my dataset. Month, year and day are in no particular order. The only thing I can be sure of is the year. I think I could do it with a RegEx but can't figure it out.

```
V1 <- c("02/04/1999", "2003/02", "01/2023")
df <- as.data.frame(V1)
```

[image]

Comment: Try `sub(".*(\\d{4}).*", "\\1", V1)` in **base R**. This looks for 4 digits groups it and replaces everything `.* ... .*` with it.

Comment: Try `V1=lubridate::ym(V1)` then `lubridate::year(V1)`

Comment: With {stringr}: `stringr::str_extract(V1, "\\d{4}")`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a list of formats to `lubridate::parse_date_time()`:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
V1 <- c("02/04/1999", "2003/02", "01/2023")
df <- as.data.frame(V1)

known_formats <- c("mdY", "Ym", "mY")
df %>% 
  mutate(year = parse_date_time(V1, known_formats) %>% year())
#>           V1 year
#> 1 02/04/1999 1999
#> 2    2003/02 2003
#> 3    01/2023 2023
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Except for (6) these alternatives use only base R.  (2) is the shortest in terms of keystrokes but (1) is nearly as short.

**1)** Match anything `.*`, capture 4 digits, `(\\d{4})`, and match anything remaining, `.*`,  and replace it all with just the first (and only) captured part, `\\1`.  Omit the `as.numeric` if you want the result to be character. No packages are used.

```
V1 <- c("02/04/1999", "2003/02", "01/2023")
as.numeric(sub(".*(\\d{4}).*", "\\1", V1))
## [1] 1999 2003 2023
```

**2)** Another way to do it is to repeatedly replace a boundary `\\b` followed by 2 characters, `..`, and a `/` or, `|`, a `/` followed by two characters, `..`, and a boundary, `\\b` with the empty string.

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\b../|/..\\b", "", V1))
## [1] 1999 2003 2023
```

**3)** This base method does not use of regular expressions.  It splits each string into components, converts those to numeric and then takes the largest.

```
sapply(strsplit(V1, "/", fixed = TRUE), \(x) max(as.numeric(x)))
## [1] 1999 2003 2023
```

**4)** Append `/01` and then use `as.Date` with a vector of possible formats giving a Date class object.  Then extract the year from that.

```
V1 |>
  paste0("/01") |>
  as.Date(c("%m/%d/%Y", "%Y/%m/%d", "%m/%Y/%d")) |>
  format("%Y") |>
  as.numeric()
## [1] 1999 2003 2023
```

**5)** Using `strcapture` extract 4 consecutive digits.

```
strcapture("(\\d{4})", V1, data.frame(year = numeric(0)))[[1]]
## [1] 1999 2003 2023
```

or

```
strcapture("(\\d{4})", V1, data.frame(year = numeric(0)))
##   year
## 1 1999
## 2 2003
## 3 2023
```

**6)** With `strapply` extract 4 consecutive digits.  Replace `as.numeric` with `c` if a character result is wanted.

```
library(gsubfn)
strapply(V1, "\\d{4}", as.numeric, simplify = TRUE)
## [1] 1999 2003 2023
```